# Question about loan word スーパーヴァイジー

Tags: academic-japanese

> スーパーヴァイジー

I'm guessing from the pronunciation that this word means supervise, but am doubting myself as I've incorrectly guessed at loan words before and had them be wrong, and I'm not having luck in dictionaries...would love any feedback if anyone knows for sure what this means. Thanks!

Edit: here is the sentence for context (I'm not so clear on what the sentence means):

> そこから，スーパーヴァイジーがスーパーヴィジョンの場で「語る」こと，「語り」を得ることが，心理臨床家としての新たな「主体性」の生成に繋がることを見出した。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess "supervisee", that is, "One who is supervised." (Context would of course help)

Comment: Thanks! I just found a definition on this page which confirms your answer: http://psychoterm.jp/applied/clinical/d3.html

Answer (score 0):

The word, スーパーヴァイジー is a form of the word スーパーヴィジョン, or "supervision", so your presumption was indeed correct. I hope I have helped you! (⌒▽⌒)